# How do I get answers to my earlier questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I've some unanswered questions, these are following

1. [Overlapping of unit length real lines?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514322/overlapping-of-unit-length-real-lines)
2. [How to draw DPDA for language $L = \{a^ncb^{2n} | n \geq1\}$over the alphabet $\Sigma =\{a,b,c\} ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503339/how-to-draw-dpda-for-language-l-ancb2n-n-geq1-over-the-alphabet)
3. [Probability that two such randomly generated strings are not identical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538214/probability-that-two-such-randomly-generated-strings-are-not-identical)
4. [Is any counter example or explanation for option (1).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499888/is-any-counter-example-or-explanation-for-option-1)
5. [Which of the following statements is always TRUE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539668/which-of-the-following-statements-is-always-true)

---

> Any suggestion to improve quality of these question if there were not?

Comment: You might have a look at [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave you an answer to questions 1 and 3. I don't know how to do question 2. For question 4 you have a comment suggesting that you already have an answer in the other question. I suggest making it clear why the other answer doesn't answer this new question. As it is now, it is unclear what you are asking/confused about. For question 5 you just posted this one hour ago and might just need to give it a bit more time. One thing, however, that discourages me from answering this question is that it is really four questions (or three since it seems like you already found an example for one of them). I suggest just asking about one of them. Make sure you explain (As carefully as you can) what about the problem that confuses you. Then, if you get an answer to that question, maybe that is enough to be able to do the others.

In general you can offer up a bounty for questions that are older than 2 days. This will, of course, cost you reputation, but it is one way to get more attention to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.